# view content of files from grep -L

Tags: grep, pipe, cat

I use `grep -L` to get a list of files that do not contain a certain string. How can I see the content of those files? Just like:

`grep -L "pattern" | cat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xargs`:

```
grep -L "pattern" | xargs cat
```

As read in `man xargs --> build and execute command lines from standard input`. So it will `cat` to those file names that `grep -L` returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cat` and use the output of `grep -L`...

```
cat $(grep -L "pattern" *.files )
```